# Tkinter to pyqt5 - Text_editor?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am porting some codes created using tkinter. It is some find and replace based on reg expression.

```
def replace():
    text_editor.replace('1.0', 'end', re.sub("\d+", '<number>', text_editor.get('1.0', 'end')))
    text_editor.replace('1.0', 'end', re.sub(r'([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]|(?:[A-Z]\.)+)', 'Acronymn', text_editor.get('1.0', 'end')))
```

What is in pyqt5 equivalent for text_editor.replace, text_editor.get ('1.0', 'end'). How to find and replace regex patterns using pyqt5?

Comment: This is a terrible implementation of find and replace in tkinter. You shouldn't be trying to implement it like this in either tkinter or pyqt5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not look for equivalent functions but understand what each piece of code does and then build the logic using the other technology.

In this `text_editor.get ('1.0', 'end')` you get all the text so if you are using QTextEdit then you should use `text_editor.toPlainText()`.

The same as `text_editor.replace('1.0', 'end', ...)` whose task is to replace all the text so it must be replaced with `text_editor.setPlainText()`.

```py
text_editor.setPlainText(re.sub("\d+", '<number>', text_editor.toPlainText()))
text_editor.setPlainText(re.sub(r'([A-Z][a-zA-Z]*[A-Z]|(?:[A-Z]\.)+)', 'Acronymn', text_editor.toPlainText()))
```

Comment: That first paragraph alone is a *very* important advice.

Comment: Does the QTextEdit widget not have the ability to search and replace within the widget itself? Getting all of the text, deleting it, and then replacing it seems very inefficient. I know that's what the OP was doing in tkinter, but that was a suboptimal solution for Tkinter.